# Runtime error in function calling using Ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am new in ionic. I have made a popover. Now I want to make tab on popover. Here I used javascript tab from www.w3schools.com. It runs but when I click a tab it shows **runtime error opencity function is not defined**. How can I fix that?

**popover.html**

```
<!-- Generated template for the PopoverComponent component -->
<div class="bg-image" style="height: 300px;">
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

**popover.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
 selector: 'popover',
  templateUrl: 'popover.html'
})

export class PopoverComponent {

 text: string;

constructor() {
console.log('Hello PopoverComponent Component');
this.text = 'Hello World';
}

}

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In popover.html have to update onclick to (click) function like:

```
<!-- Generated template for the PopoverComponent component -->
  <div class="bg-image" style="height: 300px;">
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" (click)="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
      <button class="tablinks" (click)="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
      <button class="tablinks" (click)="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
    </div>
    ....
  </div>
```

And popover.ts file like this, inside PopoverComponent class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({ selector: 'popover', templateUrl: 'popover.html' })

export class PopoverComponent {

    text: string;

    constructor() {
        console.log('Hello PopoverComponent Component');
        this.text = 'Hello World';
    }

    openCity(evt, cityName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, try to update (click)="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')"  to  (click)="openCity($event, 'Tokyo')" .

Comment: Looks like you didn't follow my answer. Here is stackblitz example URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-chjtmp

Hope it help you.

Comment: I followed your answer. When it won't work then I show you my previous code.

Comment: I am learning ionic. Can you suggest me tutorial links regarding this which is helpful for me

Comment: Happy to hear you :) 
You can visit official tutorial URL: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/tutorial/

Comment: Sorry to bother u. If i want to show default like  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs_open

Comment: I added **document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();** . but it's not working

Comment: If you want to implement tabs in a page than use ionic segment URL: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/segment/Segment/